# Different events using the same code

Tags: c#, events

I have 2 events:

```
this.lblSettings.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.HookEvent);
this.lblSettings.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.HookEvent);
```

They call this one Method:

```
    private void HookEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string method = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;

            Label label;

            if (sender is Label)
            {
                //Get the event. eg: MouseEnter, MouseLeave

                label = (Label)sender;
                label.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30);
            }
            else if (sender is PictureBox)
            {
                PictureBox picBox;
                picBox = (PictureBox)sender;
                Control control = picBox.Parent;
                if (control is Panel)
                {
                    foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
                    {
                        if (ctrl is Label)
                        {
                            label = (Label)ctrl;
                            label.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 30, 30);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

In the LABEL part, where I have the comment: "//Get the event. eg: MouseEnter, Mouseleave",

I want to see if this is the MouseEnter or the MouseLeave event being executed, because I want to do different things for each event.

Comment: You probably could use two different eventhandlers. Not easy to understand what the problem is that you want to solve.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason *not* to make this two different methods? And you even seem to use it for a third case (`sender is PictureBox`). Why do you think a "handles everything" method is necessary?

Comment: I can definitely do it in two methods, but I am experimenting. This should be possible to see in which event we currently is??

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could use lambda expressions to set a boolean to true or false (or even an Enum, who knows if you won't have 3 different calls for this event handler someday) and then call your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible as those events do not use `EventArgs` sub classes.

Edit:

you could of course create a `new StackTrace()` object and check the frames method name to see which event it is :)

Comment: Cool dude thank you. Will mark as answer in few minutes

Comment: Hmmm... that is something that can accomplish what I want to do. Thank you:).